# Calling MongoDB with Meteor helper

Tags: meteor

QQ on MongoDB and Meteor templates. I'm trying to set up a helper that will display each photo from a given DB and I'm having trouble pulling the image.

Right now a document from my DB looks like:

```
{ "order" : 19, 
   "img" : "http://foo.cdninstagram.com/photo.jpg", 
   "time" : "99999999999", 
   "user" : { "username" : "ME!", 
              "website" : "", 
              "profile_picture" : "http://foo.instagram.com/foophoto.jpg", 
              "full_name" : "Monique Rana", 
               "bio" : "", 
               "id" : "1234567" }, 
    "_id" : "abc123" }
```

Below is the code that I'm working with.

```
<template name="currentTag">
 <div class="container">
  <ul class="grid effect-8" id="grid">
   {{#each Tag}}
        <li><img src="{{Tags.img}}"></li>
   {{/each}}
   </ul>
 </div>
</template>
```

and the helper I'm building:

```
Template.currentTag.helpers({
    Tag: function () {
        return Tags.find().fetch();
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `{{img}}` instead of `{{Tags.img}}` to fix the issue. The data context in the `{{#each Tag}}` block is of the item itself.

Also you don't need `.fetch` since the template understands cursors, which are slightly more efficient i.e  `return Tags.find();`

Comment: That was it :) Thanks Akshat!